# Can't deserialize valid JSON using system.json

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe7

I write some code (rest server) that produce for me data in JSON format. When I use it in PHP it works fine, JSON is valid, everything is ok. When I use it in Delphi nothing works.

When I search internet I found:

[desearilizing JSON using SuperObject](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=216451)

but that method returns empty strings for me.

I want to use that JSON elements as array (eg. JSONValue.items[i]).

I'm using Delphi XE7 System.JSON and don't want to use superobject or any others libraries.

**How use it as array?**

I paste my code that generates JSON:

```
var
  qry: TfdQuery;
  FieldsObj: TJSONObject;
  FieldNameArray: TJSONArray;
  I: Integer;
  DataObj: TJSONObject;
  DataRows: TJSONArray;
  RowFields: TJSONArray;
  tablename:string;
begin
  tablename:='produkt';
  qry := TfdQuery.Create(Self);
  qry.SQL.Text := 'select * from produkt where (id ='''+ProductID+''')';
  qry.Connection := FDConnection1;
  qry.Open;
  FieldsObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  FieldNameArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  for I := 0 to qry.FieldCount - 1 do
    FieldNameArray.Add(qry.Fields[I].FieldName);
  FieldsObj.AddPair(TableName, FieldNameArray);
  DataObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  DataRows := TJSONArray.Create;
  qry.First;
  while not qry.Eof do
  begin
    RowFields := TJSONArray.Create;
    for I := 0 to qry.FieldCount - 1 do
      RowFields.Add(qry.Fields[I].AsString);
    DataRows.Add(RowFields);
    qry.Next;
  end;
  DataObj.AddPair('data', DataRows);
  Result := TJSONArray.Create(FieldsObj, DataObj);
  qry.Free;
```

And this is the result:

```json
{
    "ProductID": "1",
    "result": [{
        "produkt": ["id", "parent_id", "full_name", "opcja_1", "opcja_2", "opcja_3", "opcja_4", "opcja_5", "opcja_6", "opcja_7", "opcja_8", "opcja_9", "opcja_10", "opcja_11", "opcja_12", "field_address1", "field_address2", "quantity", "opis", "zdjecie1", "zdjecie2", "zdjecie3", "samples", "link_stable0", "link_stable1", "link_stable2", "price1", "price2", "price3"]
    }, {
        "data": [
            ["1", "1", "name", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "12", "10", "20", "1,2", "description of product", "http://www.vphosted.com/e6=0", "photo link2", "photo link 3", "sample project file link", "link option", "10", "link", "10", "link", "10"]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.  You seem to be saying that you have a problem consuming the JSON that this code produces and that it produces JSON which is consumed correctly by PHP, suggesting that there is nothing wrong with the producer code itself.  You really need to post your *consumer* code and explain more clearly how and why it isn't working for you.

Comment: The choosen structure of the json is very odd.

Comment: I agree with Sir Rufo - the chosen structure is very odd and the absence of JSON pairs at the lowest level will cause problems.

Comment: The JSON you posted is parsed by SuperObject like a charm. See http://rghost.ru/7vCtds8jY.view 

So Deltics is absolutely correct - your Delphi consumer code is at fault and you have to publish the consumer code if you want us be able to find the errors in it

Answer (score 1):

This would produce JSON more in the format that I would expect:

```
var
  qry: TfdQuery;
  FieldsObj: TJSONObject;
  //FieldNameArray: TJSONArray;
  I: Integer;
  DataObj: TJSONObject;
  FieldObj: TJSONObject;
  DataRows: TJSONArray;
  RowFields: TJSONArray;
  tablename:string;
begin
  tablename:='produkt';
  qry := TfdQuery.Create(Self);
  qry.SQL.Text := 'select * from produkt where (id ='''+ProductID+''')';
  qry.Connection := FDConnection1;
  qry.Open;
  FieldsObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  //FieldNameArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  //for I := 0 to qry.FieldCount - 1 do
  //  FieldNameArray.Add(qry.Fields[I].FieldName);
  //FieldsObj.AddPair(TableName, FieldNameArray);
  DataObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  DataRows := TJSONArray.Create;
  qry.First;
  while not qry.Eof do
  begin
    RowFields := TJSONArray.Create;
    for I := 0 to qry.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      FieldObj := TJSONObject.Create;
      FieldObject.AddPair(qry.Fields[I].FieldName, qry.Fields[I].AsString));
      RowFields.Add( FieldObj );
    end;
    DataRows.Add(RowFields);
    qry.Next;
  end;
  DataObj.AddPair('data', DataRows);
  Result := TJSONArray.Create(FieldsObj, DataObj);
  qry.Free;
```

If you know the record structure, though, I would prefer to use REST.JSON, which I am pretty sure ships with XE7 and is much simpler to use. You just create your object structure, create an instance of that structure, populate it with your field values and use

```
TJSON.ObjectToJsonString( fObject )
```

to create your string and

```
  iObject := TJSON.JsonToObject<TMyObject>( pTransferString );
```

to get your object back.

If you want a more complete example using this method, let me know and I will post.

Comment: ...and then changing the format would break his PHP consumer...  Well, he chosen to make two arrays rather than array of tuples, and while that is extravagant, it is still correct. His code can be worked with given the correct consumer code and lib. Than I remember DBX-JSON (which I suspect was renamed not System.JSON)  had a lot of bugs in it.